# Is this like function call arguments are defined in the BNF grammar?

Tags: c, bnf, compiler-construction

Reading [this](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf) C's BNF grammar I didn't understand which part this:

```
| postfix_exp '(' argument_exp_list ')'
| postfix_exp '('           ')'
```

does handle also a function call like `id(exp, exp)` and `id()`. Is this the single combination valid in C syntax or I'm missing something? if so, why not just:

```
| id '(' argument_exp_list ')'
| id '('            ')'
```

Comment: You can call a function via a function pointer, which can be an arbitrarily complex expression and not just 'id'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BNF grammar `id '(' argument_exp_list ')'` is actually equivalent to `postfix_exp '(' argument_exp_list ')'`
where `postfix_exp` can be a `primary_exp` as stated on its l-value.

```
postfix_exp     : primary_exp
                | postfix_exp '[' exp ']'
                | postfix_exp '(' argument_exp_list ')'
                | postfix_exp '('           ')'
                | postfix_exp '.' id
                | postfix_exp '->' id
                | postfix_exp '++'
                | postfix_exp '--'
```

where `primary_exp` is:

```
primary_exp     : id
                | const
                | string
                | '(' exp ')'
```